# Integrate Word Online Editor in my website

Tags: html, web, ms-word, integrate

As the title said, I would like to integrate the [Word Online Editor](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?ui=fr-FR) (you need an office account) in my website to facilitate the document editing for my users. Is there a way to do it ? I've been looking left and right but couldn't find a way, only how to a plug-ins for your use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. However, for viewing/rendering only you can put the Google Documents viewer in an iframe.

However, check out WOPI framework. Requires some efforts but might be what you need.